# how to get [(ngmodel)] from another component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I'm searching for the products with the pipe. The pipe is working when [(ngModel)] in product.component.html but is not working when [(ngModel)] in app.component.html.

product-find.pipe.ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product/product';

@Pipe({
  name: 'productFind'
})

export class ProductFindPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Product[], filterText?: string): Product[] {
    filterText = filterText ? filterText.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
    console.log(filterText);
    return filterText ? value.filter((x: Product) => x.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) >= 0) : value;
  }

}
```

app.component.html:

```
...

<input [(ngModel)]="filterText" name="filterText" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

...
```

product.component.html:

```
<div>
  <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let product of products |productFind:filterText" class="list-group-item">
      ...
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: are you adding product.component.html selector in app.component.html? or is it independent pages?

Comment: Yes, I added as <app-product></app-product> in app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need declare @Input decorator inside product.component.ts file.

In product.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: 'your-template-url-here
})
export class ProductComponent {

    @Input() filterText: any; 

        //rest of your code here
}
```

In product.component.html

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
       <li *ngFor="let product of products |productFind:filterText" class="list-group-item">
                        ...
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now in you app.component.html like:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="filterText" name="filterText" class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
<app-product [filterText]="filterText"><app-product>
```

Hope this will work for you!!!!

Comment: Thank you!!. This is worked. Really thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways to your problem:

1. Define filterText in product.component.ts, and use [(ngModel)]="filterText" in product.component.html. Remove input box from app.component.
2. Pass the filterText variable of parent component i.e. app.component, to child product.component using @Input

app.component.html:

```
<app-product [filterText]="filterText"></app-product>
```

product.component.ts

```
@Input
filterText : string;
```